# EJB ETL NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper during runtime

Tags: java, maven, websphere, eclipse-juno, buildpath

Root `pom` has the following dependencies,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

But during runtime, during `etl` process following error occurs,

```
EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "****" on bean "BeanId(***-ear#***-ejb.jar#***ServiceImpl, null)". Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper
```

Root cause is `NoClassDefFoundError` in the following code snippet,

```
XMLReader parser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
```

Environment used,

```
JDK 1.6.0_35
Websphere Application Server v8.0
Eclipse Juno Service Release 2
```

Full stack trace can be found here

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:703)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:123)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    ... 87 more
```

note: I have opened the `ear` archive and found the respective `jars` available. Checked `Eclipse` `java build path` also. Everything seems to be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: While the `ear` been deployed into `was` through `was console` the application works good. Seems like `Eclipse` classpath entry problem, any comments from community would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

SAXHelper is in poi-ooxml-3.16.jar. I suspect that one of the static initializers in this class is failing.
https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/util/SAXHelper.java

Comment: I have checked the class path entries in eclipse but it's fine , all jars are available. Any work around for this

Comment: Do you use classloader mode PARENT_LAST? if not, please change your ear(/war?) classloading setting. I had some strange problems with WAS Liberty recently, where we need to put bouncycastle into JVM/lib/ext ... I hope it works with PARENT_LAST ...

Comment: No luck with parent last mode in WAS, some thing wrong with class path entries in eclipse , tried editing meta files , no luck. Currently created fresh workspace , checked in new code,  built it and worked , but no luck . Currently building app from terminal and deploying through WAS admin web console and progressing my work...